# Magento API calling using HTML and javascript

Tags: javascript, api, cordova, rest, magento

I'm new to Magento and I'm developing a PhoneGap app using HTML5, CSS and Javascript. I searched many places and read Magento documentations, but couldn't get any example for authenticating, calling, getting results from the Magento APIs using javascript. I came to know that token-based authentications is needed and REST APIs are suitable for my purpose. Maily I have the following doubts.

- What are the settings I have to do in admin panel of Magento for accessing APIs.
- How to authenticate to Magento APIs in a page using HTML5 and Javascript.
- What are the APIs provided by Magento and how to call them in a page using HTML5 and Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Magento Provide the REST API , but this Require Curl to run and phonegap is based on js so you can't do in this way

you need to build your custom module with authenticate security and use via JQuery Ajax in Phonegap ( if you are using Jquery Mobile in Phonegap )

More Information about the REST API you can get here : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html

Comment: can you give me any link with JavaScript examples for api calling and how to authenticate?

Comment: First in System Config of magento create one text filed : key and store the value

then call your custom module via Ajax and post the KEY in url and validate that in your custom module Controller and if it validate then return the Requested data